# How can I add a newly added attribute to all existing configurable product as configurable option in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can I add a newly added attribute to all existing configurable product as configurable option?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? Make sure you post the context of your issue and what you've done so far to try to fix it

Comment: I was trying it manually in magento backend.

Comment: - I have added a new attribute.                                                                    - Then assigned  that attribute to the same  attribute_set.                           - Now Its show in the Product Information page. But how can I add it as a super attribute of all existing configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

In Catalog -> Manage Products -> select all product you want to change attributes -> select action to 'update Attributes' and submit -> update the attribute you want at once